# representation of hexadecimal numbers in c

Tags: c, hex

I have the following numbers which I read from a file.
 These numbers are read as `strings`. I need to represent them as `hexadecimal` numbers.
 How do I do that?

```
00000004
00000008
00000009
0000000d
00000100
```

Comment: "I need to represent them as hexadecimal numbers." - please clarify.

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert the strings in hex notation to integers?

Comment: @0xbe5077ed i want to convert these string I read(which have hex format) to hex numbers.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The compiler should see this strings which have hex format as hex numbers.

Comment: they are already hex "numbers".

Comment: Please check Stackoverflow for questions similar to yours before posting. In this case there are more then one.

Comment: `strtol()` is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to read these numbers from a file, `fscanf` is helpful for this:

```
/* note, if you're using more than 8 digits, 
    this would have to be unsigned long long and instead of %lx you would need %llx */
unsigned long h;
if (fscanf(f, "%lx", &h) == 1)
    do whatever with h
else
    error, check errno
```

You can use this check in a loop `while (fscanf(f, "%x\n", &h) == 1);` to read until the last number.

Comment: Better use `unsigned h;`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! 3more to go

Comment: `"\n"` in `"%x\n"` serves no purpose.  Suggest eliminating it.  `"%x"` consumes leading whitespace already.  `fscanf(f, "%x\n", &h)` will return 1 with or without a `\n` following the number.

Comment: "if you're using more than **4** digits, ...." as `unsigned` is only at least 0 to 65535.  Better to use `unsigned long` here.

Comment: @chux `unsigned` defaults to `unsigned long int` anyway.  Now it is `unsigned long` to make more sense.

Comment: @user9000 Suggest `"%lx\n"` to go with `unsigned long`.  BTW: "unsigned defaults to unsigned long int" is _not_ so.  `unsigned`, same as `unsigned int`, does not default to anything other than it has at least the range of `unsigned short` and no more range than `unsigned long`.  By the C spec §5.2.4.2.1, the minimum `unsigned` range is the same as minimum `unsigned short` range.

Answer (score 3):

If you have already read them into a character buffer, you could use [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) to convert from base 16 (pass 16 as the 3rd parameter).

Alternatively, if you are reading them from the file, you could [fscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) with the `%x` conversion specifier.